# How detect and restart a Node.js script running via SSH?

Tags: node.js, linux, ssh

I'm running a .js script with Node via SSH on my web host (Bluehost). I have a shared hosting, so I just downloaded/unzipped node and I run a script in SSH terminal like so:

```
> ./node/bin/node ./script.js
```

the script is continuously printing some output in an endless loop but after some time (about an hour) it gets killed by the server.

How do I detect it and restart the script?

I tried to create a cron job that runs `restart.sh` every minute in hopes to run my shell command if the process is not detected:

```
#!/bin/bash
if pgrep node >/dev/null
then
     echo "Process is running." > /home2/xxxx/txt.txt
else
     ps aux > /home2/xxxx/txt.txt
fi
```

but don't see any processes in the `txt.txt`:

```
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
xxx       2  0.0  0.0 113292  2696 ?        SN   05:27   0:00 /bin/bash /home2/xxx/restart.sh
xxx       4  0.0  0.0 155460  3988 ?        RN   05:27   0:00 ps aux
```

Comment: Why don't use use `forever` or `pm2`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pm2 for monitoring your node process

```
npm install -g pm2
```

Start a node process :

```
pm2 start -n "My process" node myscript.js
```

PM2 site : https://pm2.keymetrics.io/

PM2 will restart your script if needed.

To see node process :

```
pm2 list
```

But if your script end after 1 hour, perharps is there a problem with your code.

You can find out and error logs in : ~user/.pm2/logs

Comment: 1. I'd like to know what I asked - how to detect and restart a process.
2. pm2 installs over 180 packages with it = not happening